# Openerp 7 - QWeb - Foreach one2many

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, qweb

i have an Problem with Openerp 7.0. I want to loop over a one2many Field.
Here is my Model class:

```
class my_class(osv.osv):
        _name = "my.name"
        _inherit = 'mail.thread'
        _columns = {
                    'partners' : fields.one2many('my.other.class', 'other_id' , 'partner'),
        }
my_class()

class my_other_class(osv.osv)
       _name = 'my.other.class'
       _columns = {
             'type' : fields.char( .... ),
             ....
             'other_id' : fields.many2one('my.class')
      }
my_other_class()
```

And the XML Part File:

```
<t t-foreach="record.partners.raw_value" t-as="p">
        <div>
                Out:
                <t t-esc="p" />
                <t t-esc="p.type" />
                <t t-esc="p.cid" />
                <t t-esc="p.notification" />
        </div>
</t>
```

I have multible Partners:

- ID        TYPE        NOTIFICATION
- 1         Customer    True
- 2         Installer   True
- 3         Employee    False

If i run the Code, it only prints:
Out: 12
Out: 13

12,13 are the internal IDs

How can i loop correctly over my one2many Field? 
I found many solutions for Odoo 8, but they dont work at Openerp 7 :/

Thank you,
AntiMuffin

Comment: Qweb is not available in OpenERP 7.0 its available only in odoo 8.0 or later version

Comment: Yes, i have read that in other posts before. But i can use the most of Qweb without problems :\

Answer (score 0):

You should define a **name** column in your *my.other.class* model.
If you don't need such a column, you should at least define a **_rec_name** variable to the column you want to be used instead of name: that's because when you write

```
<t t-esc="p" />
```

odoo tries to write the object, but no default is defined, then it writes the internal id.

In your case, try to explicit

```
<t t-esc="p.id" />
```

maybe there are some problem in odoo 7 and it doesn't show the other fields.

If this doesn't work you could also try instead:

```
<t t-esc="p.id +' '+p.type+' '+p.cid+' '+p.notification" />
```

Comment: Hello, i tried it. I have set the **_rec_name** to type. But the Output is same :o  Furthermore i used  `<t t-esc="p.id + ' ' + p.type + ' ' + p.valid_from + ' ' + p.valid_until + ' ' + p.notification" />` , but the output is only "undefined undefined ...."

Comment: i do not understand the *raw_value* into the view's for-each. Try to remove it: <t t-foreach="record.partners" t-as="p">

Comment: If i dont use raw_value i get all Partners and not only the Partners i need O.o
If i log (t-log) the record.partners i get following output:
 
context
 
 Object {}
domain
 
 []
raw_value
 
 [12, 13]
0
 
 12
1
 
 13
relation
 
 "my_class.partner"
relation_field
 
 "other_id"
selectable
 
 true
string
 
 "my_class.partner"
type
 
 "one2many"
value
 
 "(2 Datensätze)"
views
 
 Object {}

Comment: please add in your code the response.render of your template. in that point you should select the partner to send to the template. you don't need raw_value.